# jquery .hover() with else if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a little delay for onmouseout event for a group of sub items in a drop down menu. But I don't want to use css transitions.
I set it with .hover() and setTimeout method but I wanted to put it only for a specific elements in menu - in this case just for sub items so I used if else statement for them. I have no idea why this if else statement does't work.

Here is my javascript code:

```
var selectors =
    {
        element: '.main-menu li:has(ul)'
    }

var opacityWorkaround = function ($element, value) {

        $element.css('opacity', value);
};

var getAnimationValues = function (visible) {
    var result = {
        visibility: visible
    };
        result.opacity = visible === 'visible' ? 1 : 0;
};

var mouseActionHandler = function ($element, visible, opacityValue) {
    $element
        .stop()
        .css("visibility", 'visible')
        .animate(getAnimationValues(visible),
        3000,
        function () {
                $(this).css("visibility", visible);
                opacityWorkaround($(this), opacityValue);
               });
};

var onMouseIn = function () {
    var $submenu = $(this).children("ul:first");
    if ($submenu) {
        mouseActionHandler($submenu, 'visible', 1);
    }
};

var onMouseOut = function () {

    var $submenu = $(this).children("ul:first");
    var $global = $('.global').children('ul');

    if ($submenu) {

               mouseActionHandler($submenu, 'hidden', 0);

    } else if ($global) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            mouseActionHandler($global, 'hidden', 0);
        },1500);
    }
};

$(selectors.element).hover(onMouseIn, onMouseOut);
```

I put 1500ms delay and the $global variable is referring to sub items in menu that I want to make disapear with that delay. I wanted to achieve this when user move mouse cursor out of 'some items >' tab.

Here is my fiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/PNz9F/1/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: i guess i'm closer to get the solution so I put another example here 
http://jsfiddle.net/8beT8/13/

Comment: Is this what your looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/PNz9F/6/

Comment: Yes Trevor, this is what I was looking for, you saved few hours of digging. Thanks a lot! I have to review basisc of conditional stataments..

Comment: Great, please mark my answer as accepted if it resolved your question.  There should be a little check mark you can click/check to the left of the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you have in your question `$submenu` always has a value so the `else if` statement is never run.  You can check for a class instead.

```
        var timeout; 
        var $submenu = $(this).children("ul:first");
        var $global = $('.global').children('ul');

        if ($(this).hasClass('menu-item')) {

                   mouseActionHandler($submenu, 'hidden', 0);
                   mouseActionHandler($global, 'hidden', 0);
                   clearTimeout(timeout);

        } else if ($(this).hasClass('global')) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                mouseActionHandler($global, 'hidden', 0);
            },1500);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just use the `:hover` selector in your code to check whether the user is hovering over the element or not and run code accordingly

Comment: Yep, I use :hover selector for all other browsers, and to make a delay i use transition-delay property but this doesn't work for IE older than version 10

Comment: No but I mean in your JQuery selector, you can use any CSS selector including :hover to see if the user if hovering over an element, then just use if($("#something:hover").length > 0) { //something } else { //something else }

Comment: and you could alternatively also use $("#something").stop(true, true).hover(function(){ // do something }, function() { //do something else });